# iPhone AVAudioPlayer loop stuttering?

Tags: iphone, loops, audio, avaudioplayer

I have  a sound that is about 2 seconds long which I have set it's it's numberOfLoops property to -1, but it has a .5 second lag between loops i want the sound to fade into itself when it is looping. Help please!

Comment: Please go through some of your previous questions and mark them as answered. Also, consider changing your Web site URL. It looks very suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use some low-level API to work with sound.I had good results using OpenAL on the iPhone. Also ideal looping is quiet hard, because your audio file should have, for example almost equivalent parameters(frequency, for example) to make people not to hear when the file is played from the beginning again.