# What is the smoothest audio API for looping iPhone sounds

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, touchesmoved

I am trying to loop a 2 second sound continuously that I am using in my touchesMoved method and want to make it play continuosly and not stutter or stop because the user stopped moving their finger and also maybe fade the sound into itself smoothly. I have tried system sounds and AVAudioPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've alreay offered you to use OpenAL [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931685/iphone-avaudioplayer-loop-stuttering/1932195#1932195)

Comment: I understand but Open AL seems like it's very complex in that there are alot of methods involved in that way of doing that

Comment: OpenAL uses low-level API so it will work faster. All code with low-level API looks complex. Nevertheless, here is good tutorial that will allow you to create simple cover class to load and play sounds using OpenAL. http://benbritten.com/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/comment-page-1/