# Best way for looping and using background sounds in iphone?

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

Lets say I am dragging my finger on screen and I have 1 second .caf sound file in my bundle.

So what is the best way to play my sound file in a loop till i am dragging my fingers. And it should stop whenever I remove touches.

I know touches implementation. Just post your views about using sound file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class, it worked pretty well for me for similar behaviour described in your question.

Comment: So you mean to say best way is first create object of AVAudioPlayer *player. And I have to call [player play] and [player pause] everytime ?

Comment: No, you can set the property `@property NSInteger numberOfLoops` to "any negative value to loop the sound indefinitely until you call the `stop` method."

Comment: I know -1 concept that it create infinite loop. But I need sound on touchesMOved... and as soon as touchesEnded it should stop. So, till touchesMoved i have to create infinite loop and when touchesEnded I have to call stop or pause ? because i have to restart again whenevr touchesMoved called.

Comment: Or use OpenAL, it's lower-level; see this post for link to overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938274/what-is-the-smoothest-audio-api-for-looping-iphone-sounds

Comment: AVAudioPlayer loops = -1 and play/pause should do the trick, and in about 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. At the moment, I don't know of a more efficient method...but here's what I used to loop my background sound. Hope this helps.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/yourAudio.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
```